# How to split a document in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> I have list input in below format

> [
> "There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. \n\nTraditional
> marketing never provided better opportunity in understanding the
> customers need. Moreover, with old school marketing aproper analysis
> and handling of data was a lot difficult. As a result, the ROI and
> efficiency were much lower as compared to AI based marketing model. 4
> key benefits are highlighted here as why seo services should use ai
> model over traditional approach.\n\nAI gives a positive influence on
> SEO. With AI, corporations can boost the precision, efficiency, and
> performance of search engine optimization techniques, comprising the
> content generated for SEO. While some of the SEOs may fear that AI
> will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an
> equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by
> finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as
> rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of
> keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and
> much more.\n\nThere are many technical seo companies around the world
> but THA is recognized as a leader in it. From advanced off page
> services to professional seo services we are the market leader.\n\nOur
> main value added proposition is ai seo optimization & business seo
> with cutting edge technologies such as data science, machine learning,
> semantic engineering, advanced search, and much more.\n\nWhile some of
> the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a
> supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your
> recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its
> algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and
> improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search
> intent analysis, and much more.\n\n\nIts algorithms, as well as rate,
> help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of
> keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and
> much more.\n"
> ]

I required code to split it by new line notation,any ways to do it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
ls = [ "There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. \n\nTraditional marketing never provided better opportunity in understanding the customers need. Moreover, with old school marketing aproper analysis and handling of data was a lot difficult. As a result, the ROI and efficiency were much lower as compared to AI based marketing model. 4 key benefits are highlighted here as why seo services should use ai model over traditional approach.\n\nAI gives a positive influence on SEO. With AI, corporations can boost the precision, efficiency, and performance of search engine optimization techniques, comprising the content generated for SEO. While some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.\n\nThere are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. From advanced off page services to professional seo services we are the market leader.\n\nOur main value added proposition is ai seo optimization & business seo with cutting edge technologies such as data science, machine learning, semantic engineering, advanced search, and much more.\n\nWhile some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.\n\n\nIts algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.\n" ]
res = ls[0].split('\n')
for n in res:
  if len(n)>0:
    print(n)
```

Step1: splitting the list using `\n`

Step2: remove the empty list and print

Result:

```
There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. 
Traditional marketing never provided better opportunity in understanding the customers need. Moreover, with old school marketing aproper analysis and handling of data was a lot difficult. As a result, the ROI and efficiency were much lower as compared to AI based marketing model. 4 key benefits are highlighted here as why seo services should use ai model over traditional approach.
AI gives a positive influence on SEO. With AI, corporations can boost the precision, efficiency, and performance of search engine optimization techniques, comprising the content generated for SEO. While some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.
There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. From advanced off page services to professional seo services we are the market leader.
Our main value added proposition is ai seo optimization & business seo with cutting edge technologies such as data science, machine learning, semantic engineering, advanced search, and much more.
While some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.
Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your list only has a single element so you can just do:

```
lst = ["There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. \n\nTraditional marketing never provided better opportunity in understanding the customers need. Moreover, with old school marketing aproper analysis and handling of data was a lot difficult. As a result, the ROI and efficiency were much lower as compared to AI based marketing model. 4 key benefits are highlighted here as why seo services should use ai model over traditional approach.\n\nAI gives a positive influence on SEO. With AI, corporations can boost the precision, efficiency, and performance of search engine optimization techniques, comprising the content generated for SEO. While some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.\n\nThere are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. From advanced off page services to professional seo services we are the market leader.\n\nOur main value added proposition is ai seo optimization & business seo with cutting edge technologies such as data science, machine learning, semantic engineering, advanced search, and much more.\n\nWhile some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.\n\n\nIts algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.\n" ]
lst = lst[0].split('\n')
for line in lst:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. 

Traditional marketing never provided better opportunity in understanding the customers need. Moreover, with old school marketing aproper analysis and handling of data was a lot difficult. As a result, the ROI and efficiency were much lower as compared to AI based marketing model. 4 key benefits are highlighted here as why seo services should use ai model over traditional approach.

AI gives a positive influence on SEO. With AI, corporations can boost the precision, efficiency, and performance of search engine optimization techniques, comprising the content generated for SEO. While some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.

There are many technical seo companies around the world but THA is recognized as a leader in it. From advanced off page services to professional seo services we are the market leader.

Our main value added proposition is ai seo optimization & business seo with cutting edge technologies such as data science, machine learning, semantic engineering, advanced search, and much more.

While some of the SEOs may fear that AI will replace their role, AI fulfils in a supporting role as an equipment.AI in SEO assists to enhance your recent SEO strategy by finding out chances, like related keywords. Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.


Its algorithms, as well as rate, help businesses expedite the method and improve the precision of keyword research, competitor analysis, search intent analysis, and much more.
```

You could add another loop if there are multiple documents in the above list.